# Python 3.1 - Send binary packed message- variable length data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a network message of the format `msgHdr+payload`. The `msgHdr` has a couple of Longs and a couple of shorts. The Payload is a variable length text. I am not sure how to format the Struct, so that I can send a packed binary stream.

The format for a single message is,

```
s = struct.Struct('> L L I I 2110s')
s.pack(*mystruct) # Then I pack it
```

However, this only works for a fixed size string of 2110. How do I use it for a variable length payload? Should I be using something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use `struct` for the header and just add the payload afterwards.

```
message = struct.pack('> L L I I', *header) + payload
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could create the format string (which is, after all, just a string), and then use it with s.pack as you describe.

If your current syntax is

```
s = struct.Struct('> L L I I 2110s')
s.pack(*mystruct)
```

all you would need to do is

```
s = struct.Struct('> L L I I %ds' % size_of_data)
s.pack(*mystruct)
```

It might help to create the header first as one struct, then the variable length section, then concatenate them.